# Scheduled task on reboot

Tags: cron, scheduling

How can I schedule a task to run on next reboot?

I understand that we have tools like `cron` and `at` to help with scheduling. But they seem to allow scheduling at a specific time and not on specific event (like rebooting).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@reboot` - from `man crontab`<sup>1</sup>:

> The following formats are also recognized:
> # schedule this job only once, when crond starts up
> @reboot date

So you could use something like:

`@reboot  /path/to/yourtask`

There are other Cron special keywords<sup>2</sup>:

**Keyword   Equivalent**
@yearly 0 0 1 1 *
@daily  0 0 * * *
@hourly 0 * * * *
@reboot Run at startup.

[1] In [dcron](http://www.jimpryor.net/linux/dcron.html) and Vixie cron

[2]  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

Comment: You should first indicate what cron implementation you are referring to.

Comment: Note that `@reboot` will also get called when the cron daemon is restarted. Not sure if this is a bug, or by design.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz Updated. Stefan: yes, the man page quote makes that point.